# database: portable way to compare two version number?

Tags: sql, string-function

What is a cross platform syntax to compare two version numbers? A version has two parts: major version and minor version, both are integer.

To compare two versions, first compare their major versions. If major versions are the same, compare their minor versions.

For example,

```
Product Table:

version  name
--------------
1.8      Bar
12.23    Foo
23.15    Hello
```

SQL

```
Select * from Product where version < "5.12"
```

It should return the first row with version 1.8. Is there any sql syntax which will works across different SQL platforms?

Specifically I'd like this to work on these platforms:

- oracle
- mysql
- SQL server
- sqlite

Comment: What do you mean portable? If you are going to compare strings as though they are numeric then you need to zero pad the numbers. So in your example you need to compare to something like `005.012.000`. `5.12` is not going to work. Waht version of SQL? In later versions it's easiest to use `FORMAT` to do this

Comment: portable means that the SQL statement will work for all major popular databases. Is FORMAT() a standard SQL function?

Comment: No. `Format` is not an ANSI SQL-99 function. I will edit your question to clarify this.

Comment: Are you able to isolate which SQL platforms you are interested in? There are 100's or platforms. Surely you can isolate a dozen.

Comment: It should work for oracle, mysql, SQL server, sqlite.

Comment: Again, I will edit your question and add this. I'm not sure what the point is. It's a fools errand to try and build something that runs transparently on both Oracle or sqllite.

Answer (score 0):

Core ANSI SQL-99 compliant:

```
select * from product
order by cast(version as int),
         cast(substring(version from position('.' in version) + 1) as int);
```

I.e. first sort by the integer part. Then sort by the "integer" following the `.` character.

Executes as:

```
SQL>create table product (version varchar(10), name varchar(10)); 
SQL>insert into product values ('1.8', 'Bar'); 
SQL>insert into product values ('12.23', 'Foo');
SQL>insert into product values ('23.15', 'Hello');
SQL>insert into product values ('1.11', 'Bye');
SQL>select * from product
SQL&order by cast(version as int),
SQL&         cast(substring(version from position('.' in version) + 1) as int); 
version    name
========== ==========
1.8        Bar
1.11       Bye
12.23      Foo
23.15      Hello

                  4 rows found
```

Note that some products have their own versions of ANSI SQL's `substring()` and `position()`. If you run into trouble try `substr(version, value)` etc.

**EDIT**: *(cast(version as int) will fail in SQL Server (and Postgres) for strings that contain decimals – a_horse_with_no_name )* Make sure you only cast the integer part as integer:

```
select * from product
order by cast(substring(version from 1 for position('.' in version) -1) as int),
         cast(substring(version from position('.' in version) + 1) as int);
```

Comment: `cast(version as int)` will fail in SQL Server (and Postgres) for strings that contain decimals

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, thanks for the info. Will edit.